# Services node retrieve -> Access restriction

Tags: services, 8

I am currently working on a project where i am exposing some nodes from a specific content type via services.
For the scope of the project I only allow retrieving of nodes from that specific content type.

I am wondering what the safest way would be to make sure that user can only try to retrieve nodes of that specific content type (or some other additional parameters [for example: only nodes that have a specific taxonomy term selected].

I started of creating a method that validates the received json object on the content type that is received.
But this does not feel like the safest way, since people can intercept the response before i get to validate it (correct?)

But it also feels like overkill to create a services view / create a custom resource just for this?

Many thanks for the opinions!

Comment: Try the Views JSON sub module included with the Views Datasource module.

Comment: to do what exactly? I can create a view that returns one node with the nid as a contextual / exposed filter. But as stated in the ticket, I wonder if there is no better solution to this